# Angular form validation - display error in another row/div

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-form-validation

The current error message displays just below the text box. But I want to display it in the entire row below to the label and text box

I tried it by moving the div like below, but it doesn't work. I see the css for `invalid-feedback` is still `display: none`. It should change to `display: block` or remove

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <label>First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <label>First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I make the code change as above, I don't get the error message, but I still get the border of the text box red.

Expect: The error message should display like below as shown in the picture

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-jhuxvm

[image]

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want the error message for your reactive form to be underneath the form labels instead of the inputs?

Comment: I want the error message to be below both label and text/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the form validation errors to display underneath each of the labels as well. Simply add the error containers `<div class="invalid-feedback">` underneath each of the form labels and give them each a style of `display: block` as they won't show until the other form errors underneath the `<input>`'s are displayed as well.

Have a look at this [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-rvznf1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). View the full page [here](https://angular-7-reactive-form-validation-rvznf1.stackblitz.io/).

[image: Form with validation errors under labels as well]

Comment: @SK. Let me know if this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually what I want is to display the error message only once. (When the message is long) The error message starts from right below to the label and it should span over to the text box, I am updating the picture in my question

Comment: Actually your tips gave me a clue, Now I am getting what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @SK. Your welcome! Want me to update my answer to reflect that? You would just remove the validation error container from under the `<input>` elements and only include it underneath the `<label>`'s and use your longer server message in that error message.